Processing messages again with a delay and N number of times. How delivery-limit works rabbitmq?
I want to have two queues: main and dead. In the main queue, messages arrive for processing; they will be sent to the dead after N number of processing attempts, which I consider using the delivery-limit policy. BUT the policy only works if I do a Nack with the requeue parameter. In my case, I don’t want the message to immediately try to be re-processed and I send it by the publisher to delayed-exchange, which sends it back to the queue after X amount of time, but in this case it does not count the number of re-sends and the message will be processed forever. similarly, the number of retries is not counted if I forward from queue to queue, although it would be logical to count each message forwarded. Little is written about this in the rabbitmq documentation, or I couldn’t find it. Perhaps I want the impossible and the number of retries will have to be counted manually?
My attempts included: creating a delayed-message exchange, and setting a delivery-limit policy on the queue. I thought it was a very cool idea that the exchange would count the delay for re-sending, and the policy would count the number of these re-processes and then send it to the dead queue.
